# Searching for text within a range and returning a comma separated list of all relevant cell values

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Forgive me, its been a while since I wrote any VBA so I know I am missing something obvious but....

I have a table along the lines of the following with a list of processes and dependent processes which are user inputted. I need some code to effectively look these up in reverse and in the upstream ID column list any IDs that have that process listed in the Next ID column as follows:

| IDs | Next IDs | Upstream IDs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID0001 | ID0002,ID0003 |  |
| ID0002 | ID0007,ID0003 | ID0001 |
| ID0003 | ID0005,ID0007 | ID0001,ID0002 |

ID0001 is listed in the upstream against the ID0002 row because it's listed in the next ID column on the ID0001 row and so on.

I tried an array formula but it doesn't seem to behave properly and only returns some of the results so thought I would try some code.

So far I have the following but its just not running:

```
Function UpstreamID(RowID As String, rng As Range) As String

'Declare the ID of that Row
Dim iCell As Range
Dim UpID As String
Dim Temp As String

'Look for it in every cell in column C (rng)

On Error GoTo err_bad_ID

For Each iCell In rng.Cells
    
    Temp = UpID
    
    If InStr(0, iCell.Text, RowID.Text, 1) > 0 Then

       UpID = Temp & ", " & ActiveSheet.Cells(iCell.Row, 1).Text
        
       Next iCell
        
    Else:
        
    Next iCell
    
UpstreamID = Trim(UpID)

Exit Function

err_bad_ID:
'error handler to handle bad IDs
    Name = "Unrecognised Process"
    Err.Clear
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: What would you expect for results in the **`Up ID`** column?

Comment: whether you're calling this from VBA or from a worksheet, please add an example of exactly how you're calling it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks all, I tweaked yesterday and looks like I now have a working solution so thank you! Will try to be clearer in my next post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is also a working array formula if you don't want to deal with VBA:

`=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A2,$B$2:$B$4)),$A$2:$A$4,""))`

Just expand the `$A$2:$A$4` and `$B$2:$B$4` as required, the formula above is for row 2 hence the `$A2` just after `SEARCH(` and can be copied down

(note: if you need case sensitive IDs, use `FIND` instead of `SEARCH`)

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for this - seems to do the trick and doesn't have the patchy data my attempt had. I will compare this with the VBA result to validate but for the size of my sheet this is probably a better option

Answer (score 1):

I have not looked at your logic other than the loop that builds your comma delimited string but you might find that this code gets you where you want to be:

```
Function UpstreamID(RowID As String, rng As Range) As String

'Declare the ID of that Row
Dim iCell As Range
Dim UpID As String

'Look for it in every cell in column C (rng)

On Error GoTo err_bad_ID

UpID = ""
For Each iCell In rng.Cells
    
    If InStr(0, iCell.Text, RowID.Text, 1) > 0 Then
       UpID = UpID & ", " & ActiveSheet.Cells(iCell.Row, 1).Text
    End If

Next iCell
    
UpstreamID = Trim(UpID)

Exit Function

err_bad_ID:
'error handler to handle bad IDs
    Name = "Unrecognised Process"
    Err.Clear
```

Comment: Thanks for this - this is now running but seems to just list all the IDs on the sheet in each cell so I think my logic is flawed!

Answer (score 1):

### Join Matches Above

**Main**

```vb
Sub JoinMatchesAbove()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const FIRST_DATA_CELL As String = "A2"
    Const SOURCE_COLUMN As Long = 1
    Const LOOKUP_COLUMN As Long = 2
    Const LOOKUP_SPLIT_DELIMITER As String = ","
    Const DESTINATION_COLUMN As Long = 3
    Const DESTINATION_JOIN_DELIMITER As String = ","
    
    ' Reference the objects i.e. workbook, worksheet and range.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(SHEET_NAME) ' worksheet
    Dim fCell As Range: Set fCell = ws.Range(FIRST_DATA_CELL)
    Dim rg As Range
    With fCell.CurrentRegion
        Set rg = fCell.Resize(.Row + .Rows.Count - fCell.Row, _
            .Column + .Columns.Count - fCell.Column) ' range
    End With
    
    ' Return the values of the source and lookup single-column ranges
    ' in 2D one-based single-column arrays held in a jagged array.
    Dim slCols(): slCols = Array(SOURCE_COLUMN, LOOKUP_COLUMN)
    Dim sJag(): sJag = GetJaggedRangeColumns(rg, slCols, 1)
    
    ' Define the destination array.
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count
    Dim dData() As String: ReDim dData(1 To rCount, 1 To 1)
    
    ' Declare additional variables used in the upcoming loop.
    Dim dict As Object, r As Long, sStr As String, lStr As String
    Dim IsFound As Boolean
    
    ' Return the joined matches in the destination array.
    For r = 1 To rCount
        sStr = CStr(sJag(1)(r, 1))
        lStr = CStr(sJag(2)(r, 1))
        If Len(sStr) > 0 And Len(lStr) > 0 Then
            ' Retrieve matching substrings.
            If IsFound Then
                dData(r, 1) = GetJoinedMatches( _
                    dict, sStr, DESTINATION_JOIN_DELIMITER)
            End If
            ' Keep track using the dictionary.
            If r < rCount Then ' nothing's below the last row to be checked
                ' Create the outer dictionary.
                If Not IsFound Then
                    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
                    IsFound = True
                End If
                ' Populate the dictionary.
                PopulateDictionary dict, sStr, lStr, _
                    LOOKUP_SPLIT_DELIMITER, DESTINATION_JOIN_DELIMITER
            End If
        'Else ' source and/or lookup values are blank; do nothing
        End If
    Next r
    
    ' Return the destination array values in the destination range.
    rg.Columns(DESTINATION_COLUMN).Value = dData
    
    ' Inform
    If IsFound Then
        MsgBox "Above-matches joined.", vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "No above-matches found.", vbExclamation
    End If

End Sub
```

**Help**

```vb
Function GetJaggedRangeColumns( _
    ByVal singleRange As Range, _
    ColumnNumbers() As Variant, _
    Optional ByVal LowerBound As Long = 1) _
As Variant
    
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = singleRange.Rows.Count
    Dim Data(): If rCount = 1 Then ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
    
    Dim cCount As Long
    cCount = UBound(ColumnNumbers) - LBound(ColumnNumbers) + 1
    Dim c As Long: c = LowerBound
    Dim Jag(): ReDim Jag(c To c + cCount - 1)
    
    Dim cItem
    
    For Each cItem In ColumnNumbers
        If rCount = 1 Then
            Data(1, 1) = singleRange.Cells(cItem).Value
        Else
            Data = singleRange.Columns(cItem).Value
        End If
        Jag(c) = Data
        c = c + 1
    Next cItem
    
    GetJaggedRangeColumns = Jag
   
End Function
```

```vb
Sub PopulateDictionary( _
        ByRef dict As Object, _
        ByVal SourceString As String, _
        ByVal LookupString As String, _
        ByVal LookupSplitDelimiter As String, _
        ByVal DestinationJoinDelimiter As String)
        
    Dim lArr() As String, lItem As Variant
    
    lArr = Split(LookupString, LookupSplitDelimiter)
    If Not dict.Exists(SourceString) Then ' first occurrence
        ' Add the inner dictionary.
        Set dict(SourceString) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        dict(SourceString).CompareMode = vbTextCompare
        ' Add the substrings to the inner dictionary (no dupes).
        For Each lItem In lArr
            If Not dict(SourceString).Exists(lItem) Then ' first occurrence
                dict(SourceString)(lItem) = Empty
            'Else ' substring already exists; do nothing
            End If
        Next lItem
    'Else ' source string already exists; this should never happen
    End If
    
End Sub
```

```vb
Function GetJoinedMatches( _
    ByVal dict As Object, _
    ByVal MatchString As String, _
    ByVal JoinDelimiter As String) _
As String
    
    ' The 'keys' ('dict.Keys') of the source dictionary ('dict')
    ' hold each (unique) string ('sItem') from the source column.
    ' Each 'item' of the source dictionary holds a lookup dictionary.
    ' The 'keys' ('dict(sItem).Keys') of the lookup dictionary ('dict(sItem)')
    ' hold each (unique) substring ('lItem') from the lookup column.
    
    Dim sItem, lItem, Result As String, IsFound As Boolean
    
    For Each sItem In dict.Keys ' source dictionary
        For Each lItem In dict(sItem).Keys 'lookup dictionary
            If lItem = MatchString Then ' match
                If Not IsFound Then
                    IsFound = True
                    Result = sItem
                Else
                    Result = Result & JoinDelimiter & sItem
                End If
                Exit For ' next 'sItem'
            End If
        Next lItem
    Next sItem
    
    If Not IsFound Then Exit Function ' no matching substrings found
    
    GetJoinedMatches = Result

End Function
```